# How to optimize config Keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, infinispan

I have deployed Keycloak on Kubernetes and am having a performance issue with Keycloak as follows:

I run 6 pods Keycloak with mode standalone HA using KUBE_PING in Kubernetes and auto scale hpa if CPU over 80%. When I test the login load with Keycloak, the threshold is only 150ccu and if over this threshold an error will occur. I see log pods Keycloak occur timeout as below

```
ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p16-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command RemoveCommand on Cache 'authenticationSessions', writing keys [f85ac151-6196-48e9-977c-048fc8bcd975]: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 2312955 from keycloak-9b6486f7-bgw8s"
ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p16-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command ReplaceCommand on Cache 'loginFailures', writing keys [LoginFailureKey [ realmId=etc-internal. userId=a76c3578-32fa-42cb-88d7-fcfdccc5f5c6 ]]: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:  ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 2201111 from keycloak-9b6486f7-bgw8s"
ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p20-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command PutKeyValueCommand on Cache 'sessions', writing keys [6a0e8cde-82b7-4824-8082-109ccfc984b4]: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 2296440 from keycloak-9b6486f7-9l9lq"
```

I see the RAM, CPU of keycloak takes up very little under 20% so it does not auto scale hpa. So I think the current configuration of Keycloak is not optimize as about number of CACHE_OWNERS, Access Token Lifespan, SSO Session Idle, SSO Session Max, etc...

I want to know what configurations to configure accordingly and can load Keycloak to 500ccu with response time ~ 3s. Please support me if you know about this !

[image: This is deployment keycloak in kubernetes]

In standalone-ha.xml config, I only update config about datasource as image below
[image: Config datasource in standalone-ha.xml config]